# MVC Listbox how do I use jQuery to select all, remove all

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC application that has two listboxes. It uses jQuery to move selected items from one listbox. I would like to know how I can use jQuery to select all the items in the first listbox and how to remove all the items in the second listbox?

The code and markup is:

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>   
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#add").click(function () {
                $("#listBoxAvail > option:selected").each(function () {
                    $(this).remove().appendTo("#listBoxSel");
                });
            });

            $("#remove").click(function () {
                $("#listBoxSel > option:selected").each(function () {
                    $(this).remove().appendTo("#listBoxAvail");
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
           @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedAttributes, Model.Attributes, new {id="listBoxAvail", SIZE = 5} ) 

            <button type="button" id="add">MoveRight</button>

            <button type="button" id="remove">"MoveLeft"></button>

            <button type="button" id="remove-all">RemAll</button>

            <button type="button" id="select-all">SelAll</button>

            @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedAttributes2, Model.SelectedItems, new { id = "listBoxSel", SIZE = 5})
        } 
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove all element just make all option selected for `listBoxSel` select and trigger remove button's click action.
 The same for select all:

```js
$("#add").click(function () {
  $("#listBoxAvail > option:selected").each(function () {
    $(this).remove().appendTo("#listBoxSel");
  });
});

$("#remove").click(function () {
  $("#listBoxSel > option:selected").each(function () {
    $(this).remove().appendTo("#listBoxAvail");
  });
});

$("#remove-all").on("click", function (event){
   $('#listBoxSel option').prop('selected', true);
   $("#remove").trigger("click");
})
 

$("#select-all").on("click", function (event){
   $('#listBoxAvail  option').prop('selected', true);
   $("#add").trigger("click");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select option multiple="true" id="listBoxAvail">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="add" value="add">
<input type="button" id="select-all" value="select all">
<input type="button" id="remove" value="remove">
<input type="button" id="remove-all" value="remove all">
<select option multiple="true" id="listBoxSel">
</select>
```

**UPDATE:**

As  Stephen Muecke suggested in comment thread below, more proper solution to select-all

```
$('#move').click(function(){
    $('#first option').appendTo($('#second'));
});
```

see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lfd5upqv/)

Comment: Far better to use `$("#remove-all").click(function () { $("#listBoxSel option")appendTo("#listBoxAvail"); }); });` to avoid the duplicate loops your code is doing. And it does not make the options selected when they are moved to the 2nd `select` which may not be OP's intention

Comment: But your suggested code does not remove items from source select

Comment: Of course it does. A DOM element cant be in 2 containing elements at the same time. When you append an element to another element it moves it (not copies it). For that you would need to clone the element first

Comment: Could you make jsfidlle, I can't make your code work

Comment: Thanks then you could make it answer which is more proper than mine

Comment: Your answer works and OP did not indicate if he wanted them to be `selected` or not after they are moved, so no need for another answer or for you to lose rep. I was just making a suggested improvement which OP can adopt or ignore.

Comment: Although `Please avoid extended discussions in comments` warning let me put one more comment: Learning better solutions is more important then eraning reputation. so let me update my answer including your code